# Why do only some calls invalidate/replace tokens with devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using `devise_token_auth` for an API-only application. It seems that tokens are only invalidated and new values provided in the headers with certain calls. Specifically, it looks like `PUT` requests don't invalidate the previously provided token info. Why is that? I was planning to update the stored values from the previous token after every call and this means sometimes the values aren't there. I can work around that with conditionals, but I'd like to understand what the reason for this is and/or if this is something that can be configured.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation under token management there's a [sub-section about batch requests](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-batch-requests) pointing to the `batch_request_buffer_throttle` variable in the `devise_token_auth.rb` initializer. I guess if you set that to 0 the behaviour will match your expectations.